# minimum jump to reach to end

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Question statement:
Given array: [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0]
output: minimum steps required to reach to end

Conditions:

- step on 0 is exit
- you can take max of 1 step or 2 steps at a time.

I have done using without DP, Is a DP solution present for this problem.

My code:

```
def minjump(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    if n <= 0 or arr[0] == 0:
        return 0

    index = jump = 0
    while index < n:
        if index == n-1:
            return jump

        if arr[index] == 0 and arr[index+1] == 0:
            return 0

        if arr[index] == 1:
            if index < n-2 and arr[index+2] == 1:
                jump +=1
                index +=2
            else:
                jump += 1
                index += 1
    return jump
```

Comment: You can construct a dp solution, moving from right to left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A naïve solution with no memoization simply recurses through the list taking both one or two steps and retaining the minimum steps needed:

```py
def min_steps(array, current_count, current_position):
   if current_position >= len(array):  # Terminal condition if you've reached the end
       return current_count
   return (
       min(
           min_steps(array, current_count + 1, current_position + 1),
           min_steps(array, current_count + 1, current_position + 2),
       )  # minimum count after taking one step or two
       if array[current_position]  # if current step is valid (non-zero)
       else float("inf")  # else, return float.infinity (fine since we're not imposing types on this prototype)
   )


def minjump(arr):
   result = min_steps(arr, 0, 0)
   return 0 if result == float("inf") else result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve a more general problem using dp, in the pseudocode bellow k represents the maximum number of steps you can jump:

```
int n = arr.Length
int dp[n]
for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
    int lowerBound = max(i - k, 0)
    for (j = i - 1; j >= lowerBound; j--) {
        if (arr[j] == 1 && (j == 0 || dp[j] > 0)) {
            dp[i] = min(dp[i], 1 + dp[j])
        }
    }
}
return dp[n - 1]
```